# Typographical error? Integral curve of $y^2dx-x^2dy=xy$ passing through point (1,1)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The following first-order differential equation and boundary condition appears in Section 2.7, Problem 14 of *An introduction to the theory of Differential Equations* by Walter Leighton.

$y^2dx-x^2dy=xy$, passing through (1,1)

The solution is given as

$x^y=y^x$

Which by inspection must reduce to $y=x$ to pass through the point (1,1). Clearly, this does not satisfy the ODE in the problem.

The book I've found is quite full of errors and I would not be surprised if the given ODE is incorrect.

Is the ODE even solvable in any sense? The lack of differentials on the RHS is disturbing, and my attempts to numerically solve the ODE have failed to converge on a solution.

Comment: I can't make sense of the differential equation. Unless I'm missing something obvious, the lack of any differential on the right hand side renders the equation meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely something is missing. In order that the solution satisfies an equation, one way to do is to change the equation to $$y^2dx-x^2dy=xy(\ln(y)dx-\ln(x)dy).$$ Or just forget about it and move on.